# How can I accept multiple deserialization names for the same Serde field?

Tags: rust, serde, serde-json

I am trying to use Serde to deserialize JSON (`serde-json`) and XML (`serde-xml-rs`) files based on the following struct:

```
use serde_derive::Deserialize;

#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Deserialize)]
pub struct SchemaConfig {
    pub name: String,
    #[serde(rename = "Cube")]
    pub cubes: Vec<CubeConfig>,
}
```

The fields I am deserializing on have different names based on the file type. In this case, I would like for a JSON file to have a `cubes` key with a list of cubes, but the equivalent in XML would be multiple `<Cube />` elements.

I can't figure out how to accept both `cubes` and `Cube` as keys for the deserialization. The closest thing I found was the `#[serde(rename = "Cube")]` option but when I use that the JSON deserialization stops working since it only accepts the `Cube` key. If I remove that option, the XML deserialization stops working as it then only accepts `cubes` as the key.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this in Serde?

Answer (score 19):

I encourage you to read the Serde documentation. The [field attributes](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html) chapter introduces the [`alias` attribute](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#alias), emphasis mine:

> `#[serde(alias = "name")]`
>
> Deserialize this field from the given name or from its Rust name. May
>   be repeated to specify **multiple possible names for the same field**.

```
use serde::Deserialize; // 1.0.88
use serde_json; // 1.0.38

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct SchemaConfig {
    #[serde(alias = "fancy_square", alias = "KUBE")]
    cube: [i32; 3],
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<std::error::Error>> {
    let input1 = r#"{
        "fancy_square": [1, 2, 3]
    }"#;

    let input2 = r#"{
        "KUBE": [4, 5, 6]
    }"#;

    let one: SchemaConfig = serde_json::from_str(input1)?;
    let two: SchemaConfig = serde_json::from_str(input2)?;

    println!("{:?}", one);
    println!("{:?}", two);

    Ok(())
}
```

---

> I would like for a JSON file to have a `cubes` key with a list of cubes, but the equivalent in XML would be multiple `<Cube />` elements.

This certainly sounds like you want two different *structures* to your files. In that case, look at something like:

- [How to transform fields during deserialization using Serde?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46753955/155423)
- [How do I serialize an enum without including the name of the enum variant?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52034764/155423)

Comment: Thank you for the code sample. I did read the documentation, but it wasn't clear to me from the documentation how to specify multiple `alias` values. Your code sample here makes it perfectly clear. 

Comment: This looks the only workaround. but it's buggy. think about `fancy_square` and `KUBE` can be in the same file or different file.