# How to use string values in enum and avoid "expected `isize`, found `&str`"?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use an `enum` but I need string values to be saved in DB, Redis etc.

```rust
pub enum Place {
  Square = "1",
  House = "2",
  Office = "3",
  // and so on... Garage = "4",
}
```

But the compiler throws with:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  |
3 |     Square = "1",
  |             ^^^ expected `isize`, found `&str`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  |
4 |     House = "2",
  |            ^^^ expected `isize`, found `&str`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  |
5 |     Office = "3",
  |            ^^^ expected `isize`, found `&str`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
```

**Why?**

What does it mean?

Comment: Alternatively, you may be looking for how to [serialize your enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52034764/how-do-i-serialize-an-enum-without-including-the-name-of-the-enum-variant)

Comment: Is there a way I can get the discriminant of each enum where I need it?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.discriminant.html

Comment: Yeah. I saw it but is unstable and I cannot use it. It's crazy I can't do a simple thing like this.

Comment: It is **const unstable** It can be used in stable but not as `const fn`, what I mean is: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=aa7d03b0e8217d4263592e5a3b7accf8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If what you need is a string representation of the values of your enum, then the work should be done in another trait implementation, namely [Display](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html). Implementing this trait allows your enum to implement the `ToString` trait for free.

You'd do something like:

```
use std::fmt;

pub enum Place {
    Square,
    House,
    Office,
}

impl fmt::Display for Place {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(
            f,
            "{}",
            match self {
                Self::Square => "1",
                Self::House => "2",
                Self::Office => "3",
            }
        )
    }
}

fn main() {
    let place = Place::Office;
    println!("{place}"); // --> prints 3

    let s = place.to_string();
    println!("{s}"); // --> also prints 3
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=669bd7bd0cbe0183b15078aa0efcecb0)